# How to Authenticate with Alexa Voice Service from Android?

Tags: android, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to connect to Alexa Voice Service from an Android app following the directions on this page: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-an-android-or-ios-mobile-app

```
Bundle options = new Bundle();
String scope_data = "{\"alexa:all\":{\"productID\":\"" + PRODUCT_ID +
                    "\", \"productInstanceAttributes\":           {\"deviceSerialNumber\":\"" + PRODUCT_DSN + "\"}}}";
options.putString(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.SCOPE_DATA.val, scope_data);
options.putBoolean(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.GET_AUTH_CODE.val, true);
options.putString(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.CODE_CHALLENGE.val, CODE_CHALLENGE);
options.putString(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD.val, "S256");
mAuthManager.authorize(APP_SCOPES, options, new AuthorizeListener());
```

First, I don't know what APP_SCOPES should be. I set it to:

```
protected static final String[] APP_SCOPE = new String[]{"profile", "postal_code"};
```

but I get an error from the server

```
AuthError cat= INTERNAL type=ERROR_SERVER_REPSONSE - com.amazon.identity.auth.device.AuthError: Error=invalid_scope error_description=An unknown scope was requested
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **APP_SCOPE** is : "alexa:all"

The **PRODUCT_DSN** can be anything you want, "1234" as per suggestion from Joshua Frank (https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=18973#18973)

The **PRODUCT_ID** is the ID in the AVS Developper Portal (https://developer.amazon.com/edw/home.html#/avs/list)

The **CODE_CHALLENGE** the Client Secret in the Security Profile of your application (should be already hashed in S256)

Comment: The instructions make it sound like you need to generate your own code challenge. That was one of my issues.

Comment: The documentation is not really clear... well, it's **beta**

Comment: I agree with you on APP_SCOPE and PRODUCT_DSN. I just don't get it on PRODUCT_ID and CODE_CHALLENGE. Why do you take the PRODUCT ID from AVS Developer Portal while the documents https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-an-android-or-ios-mobile-app and http://login.amazon.com/ios#install_login_with_amazon_library only mention about App Console: http://login.amazon.com/manageApps ? And CODE_CHALLENGE is described at the top of my first link, why do you say it's taken from the Client Secret in Security Profile?

Comment: That might not be true anymore, the answer was given when AVS was still in beta. If the answer is not good anymore and you have a better answer, please go ahead, it might help someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the APP_SCOPES variable, it is actually with the PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_DSN variables passed in the scope data.

I faced this exact same issue and have raised a query in amazon developers forum on what needs to be passed in those variables - [Alexa authentication issue using beta SDK](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=6048&tstart=0)

Once the PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_DSN & CODE_CHALLENGE variables are determined then the authentication should be pretty much straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

The APP_SCOPE should be "alexa:all"