# Cannot get authorization token access to Amazon alexa on android app

Tags: android, httpclient, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I created a Security profile and got the CODE_CHALLENGE from it.I referred [How to Authenticate with Alexa Voice Service from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798899/how-to-authenticate-with-alexa-voice-service-from-android).

```
private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "my_device";
private static final String PRODUCT_DSN = "123";
private static final String CODE_CHALLENGE = "ca9416f4aaafc68f0722e38410f9acd18094a9b9f59e0c10a1cf8930b3d8600f";
private static final String CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD = "S256";


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amazon_login);

    requestContext = RequestContext.create(this);
    requestContext.registerListener(new AuthorizeListenerImpl());

    buttonAmazon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_amazon);
    buttonAmazon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final JSONObject scopeData = new JSONObject();
            final JSONObject productInstanceAttributes = new JSONObject();

            try {
                productInstanceAttributes.put("deviceSerialNumber", PRODUCT_DSN);
                scopeData.put("productInstanceAttributes", productInstanceAttributes);
                scopeData.put("productID", PRODUCT_ID);

                AuthorizationManager.authorize(new AuthorizeRequest.Builder(requestContext)
                        .addScope(ScopeFactory.scopeNamed("alexa:all", scopeData))
                        .forGrantType(AuthorizeRequest.GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                        .withProofKeyParameters(CODE_CHALLENGE, CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD)
                        .build());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // handle exception here
            }

        }
    });
}
private class AuthorizeListenerImpl extends AuthorizeListener {

    /* Authorization was completed successfully. */
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final AuthorizeResult authorizeResult) {
        final String authorizationCode = authorizeResult.getAuthorizationCode();
        final String redirectUri = authorizeResult.getRedirectURI();
        final String clientId = authorizeResult.getClientId();
        Log.d("AmazonLoginActivity","success"+" "+authorizationCode+" "+redirectUri+" "+clientId);
        postData(authorizationCode,redirectUri,clientId);

    }

    /* There was an error during the attempt to authorize the application. */
    @Override
    public void onError(final AuthError authError) {
    }

    /* Authorization was cancelled before it could be completed. */
    @Override
    public void onCancel(final AuthCancellation authCancellation) {
    }
}


public void postData(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", s1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", s2));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", s3));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code_verifier","1234"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName()
                    + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
        }

        Log.d("Response",responseStr);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

And I am getting unauthorized_client exception.This is my android log.

```
06-23 18:31:02.496 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationHelper: Return auth code success 
06-23 18:31:02.500 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot D/AmazonLoginActivity: success ANkBjQgTSnsVwfcQCqrU amzn://gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot amzn1.application-oa2-client.bd04c0584c0c4a1296bf3c1f14f9a831 
06-23 18:31:02.611 29161-29161/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1496318b time:21809219 
06-23 18:31:04.543 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Server ,Value : Server 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Date ,Value : Fri, 23 Jun 2017 13:00:42 GMT 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Content-Type ,Value : application/json 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Content-Length ,Value : 92 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Connection ,Value : keep-alive 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : x-amzn-RequestId ,Value : f6f231ed-5813-11e7-88b7-1d51a9cde1df 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : X-Amz-Date ,Value : Fri, 23 Jun 2017 13:00:42 GMT 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : x-amzn-ErrorType ,Value : OA2UnauthorizedClientException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.panda/ 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Cache-Control ,Value : no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Pragma ,Value : no-cache 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot I/System.out: Key : Vary ,Value : Accept-Encoding,User-Agent 
06-23 18:31:04.544 29161-29523/gct.venkatesh.com.alexabot D/Response: {"error_description":"Not authorized for requested operation","error":"unauthorized_client"
```

Answer (score -2):

@Venkatesh:

Generate the codeVerifier and codeChallenge:

```
String codeVerifier = generateCodeVerifier();
String codeChallenge = generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier, "S256");







 private String generateCodeVerifier() {
                String randomOctetSequence = generateRandomOctetSequence(100);
                String codeVerifier = base64UrlEncode(randomOctetSequence.getBytes());
                return codeVerifier;
            }

            private String generateRandomOctetSequence(int count) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.~".toCharArray();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

    private String generateCodeChallenge(String codeVerifier, String codeChallengeMethod) {
                String codeChallenge = "";
                if ("S256".equalsIgnoreCase(codeChallengeMethod)) {
                    try {
                        byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(
                                codeVerifier.getBytes());
                        codeChallenge = base64UrlEncode(
                                digest);
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fall back to code_challenge_method = "plain" codeChallenge = codeVerifier;
                }
                return codeChallenge;
            }

    private String base64UrlEncode(byte[] arg) {
                String s = new String(Base64.encode(arg, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP));
                s = s.split("=")[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
                s = s.replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
                s = s.replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
                return s;
            }
```

Plz see my comment here (Source):https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/issues/987

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)